# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; I can't find that I did wrong

Tags: mysql, database, insert

```
mysql> DESC transaction;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| from  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| to    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cost  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO transaction (title, from, to, cost) VALUES ('Ham', 1, 4, 9000);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to, cost) VA
LUES ('Ham', 1, 4, 9000)' at line 1
```

I tried to insert data to 'transaction' table. I think the query is fine but it is saying error. What's is my problem? Please, help me!

Comment: I figured it out. I think it was because of using 'from' in query. Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

- Avoid using reserved keywords as column names.
- Still if you need to use them, use double quotes while referencing them. You'll get a syntax error while writing a select statement as well. Do not forget to use them with **double quotes**

Use:

```
select "from", cost from...
```

instead of:

```
select from, cost from...
```

Answer (score 1):

CHANGE INSERT Tsql TO :

```
INSERT INTO `transaction` (`title`, `from`, `to`, `cost`) VALUES ('Ham', 1, 4, 9000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, certain words like SELECT, INSERT, FROM etc. are reserved words. Since they have a special meaning, MySQL treats it as a syntax error whenever you use them as a table name, column name, or another kind of identifier - unless you surround the identifier with backticks.

For more details, Please see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html